# Candy Machine mintV2: Incorrect minting fee

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, metaplex, candy-machine

I am trying to mint an NFT from candy machine on Devnet, I tried setting the mint price through Sol payment guard, but it always takes the same fee around 0.02 Sol and not the actual amount,
here we can see the actual price of the candy guard(Sol payment) is 0.6 Sol
[image]

when I try to mint using MintV2 instruction, it shows the same fee for all the NFTs, It the same fee in the image below.

[image]

```
const nftMint =  generateSigner(props.umi)  
const transaction = await transactionBuilder()
  .add(setComputeUnitLimit(props.umi, { units: 800_000 }))
  .add(
    mintV2(props.umi, {
      candyMachine: candyMachine.publicKey,
      candyGuard: candyGuard.publicKey,
      nftMint,
      collectionMint:props.mintedNft.collectionMintId,
      collectionUpdateAuthority:props.mintedNft.collectionUpdateAuthorityId,
        mintArgs: {
          mintLimit: some({ id: 1 }),
          solPayment: some({destination: candyMachine.authority }),
      },
    })
  )
  // .sendAndConfirm(props.umi);
 
  const { signature } = await transaction.sendAndConfirm(props.umi, {
    confirm: { commitment: "confirmed" },
    });
```